# How do I expose member objects via using CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

Everywhere I see tutorials on how to compile assemblies using the System.CodeDom namespace.

But how can I access a member object of an assembly from a runtime compiled assembly (I'm not talking about accessing a class, I want to access a specific member variable)? In Microsoft Script Control it can be done with the AddObject method.

I guess if the assembly that is compiled at runtime behaves like every other ordinary assembly, then I should use .NET remoting? But isn't it an overkill? I wish there was an easier way.

Comment: Remoting? You mean Reflection?

Comment: No, I mean the API for interprocess communication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting

Answer (score 0):

By passing your object to an appropriate method in the runtime compiled assembly?

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will be the solution, but I will look into it deeper, when I have the time.